# Windows automount drive by label

Tags: windows, ntfs, automount

Is there any way to **automount** windows drives (volumes) by label on an ntfs folder?
I would like to have something similar to what is done in most linux distros (assign a folder as a mountpoint automatically)

Example:
The E:\ drive has a label Photos. So, windows automatically mount E:\ in c:\mount\Photos

Comment: Why would you do both? If I'm not mistaken it's mostly a one time setup in Windows. You could automate it with a script.

Comment: Actually, I don't need both. But they need to automount because I have many usb harddrives with a lot of pictures from my sister's job.

Today, I'm backing up this to a linux server, using borg + wsl. For organizational reasons, we need to label each drive according to day, month and year works. In this way, borg can backup whole thing to sane folders. So, my backups looks like this:

2018_2018-03-08
Current_work_2018-03-07
2019_2018-03-7

And so on

Does this clarify my reasons?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be done automatically for a new drive, but you could try to configure the drive so everytime you plug it in, it will automount to a `c:\path_to_drive`.

For that plug the drive in and open a,

`cmd` WindowsKey + R, type cmd

`diskpart`

`list volume` Here you check the number of the drive

`select volume your_volume_number_right_here` >

`assign c:\the\path\you\like`

More info [Here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/disk-management/assign-a-mount-point-folder-path-to-a-drive#BKMK_CMD)